# why does my roundcube create a cube when here it creates a ball?

Tags: modeling, mesh

i think the ball shape i want was called a polyshpere or a quadsphere.
im using this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlaMfIgS2ns
the roundcube thing im trying to make is at 1:58 seconds into the video
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a bad default setting, to have a sphere you need to go into the *Operator* box and increase the *Radius* up to 1:

[image]

Comment: that was the problem, seems so obvious now thank you moonboots